# Install TCP Wrappers in Slackware 14.2

Tags: linux, package, package-managers, slackware

How to install `TCP Wrappers` using the appropriate package manager? When I run `pkgtool`, I can see in the list that tcp_wrappers is included `tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1`. I want to install it.

I tried the command below, with no luck.

```
installpkg tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1.tgz
```

Whenever I run the command above, it says

```
Cannot install, file not found.
```

So I navigated to /var/log/packages, where the list of Slackware packages are listed and I found there `tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1` file. So what I did is:

```
mv tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1 tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1.tgz
installpkg tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1.tgz
```

The prompt message is :

```
Verifying package tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1.tgz
gzip : stdin : not in gzip format
Installing package tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1.tgz:
PACKAGE DESCRIPTION:
WARNING: Package has not been created with 'makepkg'
Package tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1.tgz installed.
```

After, I verified whether the tcp_wrappers is already installed using the commands below, with no luck.

```
rpm -q tcp_wrappers
rpm -q tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1
rpm -q tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1.tgz
```

It just say:

```
package tcp_wrappers is not installed
package tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1 is not installed
package tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1.tgz is not installed
```

what shall I do?

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: @itzFlubby --> It says cannot install. file not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is in */var/log/packages*, then it's already installed. Files in this directory are simple text files with package description, list of installed files etc. Try for example:

```
less /var/log/packages/tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1
```

On my box it shows:

```
PACKAGE NAME:     tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1
COMPRESSED PACKAGE SIZE:     77.0K
UNCOMPRESSED PACKAGE SIZE:     340K
PACKAGE LOCATION: /usb-stick/slackware64/n/tcp_wrappers-7.6-x86_64-1.txz
PACKAGE DESCRIPTION:
tcp_wrappers: tcp_wrappers (TCP/IP daemon wrapper library and utilities)
tcp_wrappers:
tcp_wrappers: With this package you can monitor and filter incoming requests for
tcp_wrappers: network services for access control, and detection things like host
tcp_wrappers: name spoofing and host address spoofing.  Nearly all the network
tcp_wrappers: daemons on Slackware are "wrapped" using this library, and most
tcp_wrappers: daemons in /etc/inetd.conf use tcp_wrappers' tcpd wrapper daemon.
tcp_wrappers: If you plan to do much networking, you will need tcp_wrappers.
tcp_wrappers:
tcp_wrappers: tcp_wrappers was written by Wietse Venema.
tcp_wrappers:
FILE LIST:
./
install/
install/slack-desc
usr/
usr/doc/
usr/doc/tcp_wrappers_7.6/
usr/doc/tcp_wrappers_7.6/BLURB
usr/doc/tcp_wrappers_7.6/CHANGES
usr/doc/tcp_wrappers_7.6/DISCLAIMER
usr/doc/tcp_wrappers_7.6/README
usr/doc/tcp_wrappers_7.6/README.NIS
usr/include/
usr/include/tcpd.h
[ cut ]
```

`rpm` is RedHat tool. It will not show this package as installed, because `pkgtool` used by Slackware is not related to rpm in any way - it doesn't update rpm package database. `rpm` is installed in Slackware only for installing rpm packages, not to manage packages installed by native `pkgtool`.

Answer (score 1):

To test, whether the packet has been installed or not, one should simply issue the command:

```
slackpkg search tcp_wrappers
```

Output will be (e.g. on Slackware 12.0)

```
The list below shows all packages with the selected pattern.

[ installed ] - tcp_wrappers-7.6-i486-1
```

The `slackpkg' allows to install, remove, list etc packets in the system. Please see the get the help option.
As for TCP_wrappers, it is included in Slackware long ago, I think